# How to convert building outlines to Polygons?

Tags: qgis, algorithm, dissolve

I have line vector layer which contains contours of buildings 
in the form of separate segments. I want to convert lines to polygons (QGiS 2.17) but it doesn't work.

I'm trying to solve this problem as follows: first off by using algorithm *dissolve* for all objects, and afterwards by using algorithm *multipart to singlepart*. Unfortunately, dissolving takes a long time.

How can I do this faster and easier?

Comment: You could dissolve smaller selections first to see how it goes. the line to polygon tool goes along a table field with numbers wich indicate the direction to build the polygon. or if you leave that as default it just builds the polygon like you build the lines. and can you get more specific with your problem? is the problem only to do it faster or really the line to polygon process?